# FreeRDP on Kubuntu: Autohotkey on remote, Autokey local

Tags: kubuntu, rdp, autokey

On my local machine (Kubuntu), I use Autokey. On the remote machine (Windows) I use Autohotkey. I have lots of shortcuts setup on both machines. When I'm on the server through FreeRPD and I use a shortcut (like CTRL-NUMPAD2) that exists on both machines, both routines run on the server. I switch back and forth often, so I'd rather not suspend Autokey on the local machine. When I'm running FreeRDP full screen, is there a way to have only the shortcut on the remote machine heard?

(This same issue also happens for the meta key: while in fullscreen, I would expect FreeRDP to capture keyboard, but it doesn't.)

Comment: from question it is ubuntu 21.10.

Comment: Ubuntu version is irrelevant. FreeRDP has had this issue since I first installed 18, it's just lately become enough of an issue to post over.